# How to install Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: vpn, cisco

I have Win7 64bit. Have Cisco VPN Client winx64-msi-5.0.07.0440-k9.
Now i try to install it. But after i click first "Next" button in istaller i get error:

```
"installation ended prematurely because of an error"
```

Google says that i shall uncheck all checkboxes into ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) in adapter setting but its not help.
How to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AnyConnect VPN Client, Cisco VPN client does not support x64

The Cisco VPN Client supports:

XP, Vista (x86/32-bit only), Windows 7 (x86/32-bit only), **and Windows x64 (64-bit). Windows x64 support also provided by Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client**
Linux (Intel)
Mac OS X 10.4 and 10.5
Solaris UltraSPARC (32- and 64-bit)

Source: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps2308/index.html

If you can user other client you may like to test this one http://www.shrew.net

Comment: I've found this it might be useful in your trouble shoot: https://rquintino.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/cisco-vpn-client-64-bits-windows-7-a-few-setup-problems-solutions/ and https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2045330 did not knew that cisco had made a x64 version.